# What is the different between these?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a method like this in wcf service

```
public string PostAllSurveList(List<Survey> surveyList)
{
    var surveyDbList = ConstructDbServeyList(surveyList);
    foreach (var survey in surveyDbList)
    {
        _db.surveys.Add(survey);
    }
    _db.SaveChanges();
    return "Successfully Saved";
}
```

when I call this method in C# by the following way it's working fine

```
var surveys = new Survey[]{new Survey{ Id = 1, ConsumerName = "atish"},};

string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(surveys);
```

but not working in the following way

```
var surveys = new List<Survey>{ new Survey { Id = 1, ConsumerName = "atish"}};

string reply = client.PostAllSurveList(surveys);
```

getting compile time error.

My question is why this happens.

Comment: What is the compiler error? Might be useful in diagnosis, you know.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: ConsumeSurveyService.SurveyService.DataGetPostService.PostAllSurveList(ConsumeS‌​urveyService.SurveyService.Survey[])' has some invalid arguments F:\BS_Intern\Suvey Web Service\Servey\ConsumeSurveyService\Program.cs 20 28 ConsumeSurveyService

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the **Collection type** used by WCF reference when connecting to it. This can be done when you are creating or editing the reference. For your convenience see attached screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you create the WCF service reference you can specify what type will be used for collections (independent on how it is declared on the server side). In your case the service client is generated to use arrays and not lists.

You need to change that service reference configuration.

Comment: Should select ...`Generic.List` from the configuration pane.